# Error when check out code from SVN server

Tags: php, svn

I have SVN server to control source code version

I can checkout my code when I use TortoiseSVN or use command line.

Here is some information:

1. SVN server
   [image]
2. Checkout code by using TortoiseSVN in Windows
   [image]
3. Chechout code by using commandline in Ubuntu (Web server)

I use this command

```
root@controller1:/var/www/onecloud# svn co --force --username hoang --password gcsvn123 http://203.162.141.79/onecloud /var/www/onecloud
```

[image]

Then I write PHP code to update version auto (don't use TortoiseSVN or use command line).

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$result= exec('svn co --force --username hoang --password gcsvn123 http://203.162.141.79/onecloud /var/www/onecloud 2>&1',$out);
print_r($out);
```

But when I run my code, it show this error:

```
Array ( [0] => svn: E155004: Run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details) [1] => svn: E155004: Working copy '/var/www/onecloud' locked [2] => svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database [3] => svn: E200031: Additional errors: [4] => svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database )
```

I have run command line `svn cleanup`, but it seem doesn't work.

Not:

```
My SVN server is 203.162.141.79
My web server is 203.162.141.26
```

Comment: You should never include username and password nor a real  IP or URL, except it is important to solve the problem!

Comment: Do you remove the directory contents before checking out? I remind you `checkout` is the command to create a working copy, not something you run on an existing working copy, so the directory **must be empty**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found directory `.svn` in my code after checkout.

When I use these two commands:

```
chmod -R 777 .svn/
chown www-data:www-data .svn/
```

it works.

[image]